# In statement for LINQ to objects

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

Is there an equivalent of a SQL IN statement in LINQ to objects?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes - [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx).

```
var desiredNames = new[] { "Jon", "Marc" };

var people = new[]
{
    new { FirstName="Jon", Surname="Skeet" },
    new { FirstName="Marc", Surname="Gravell" },
    new { FirstName="Jeff", Surname="Atwood" }
};

var matches = people.Where(person => desiredNames.Contains(person.FirstName));

foreach (var person in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person);
}
```

(In LINQ to SQL this ends up as an "IN" query.)

Note that in LINQ to Objects the above isn't really very efficient. You'd be better off with a join:

```
var matches = from person in people
              join name in desiredNames on person.FirstName equals name
              select person;
```

(This could still be done with dot notation of course, but it ends up being somewhat messier.)

Comment: Why the inner join is not prefered here? You know if the people contain 10 records and desiredNames  contains 2, it will iterate 20 times in background, irrespective of the fact that whether there is a match or not.

Comment: @PankajGarg: Please don't pester like this - I won't always be able to respond immediately. Did you read the bottom part of my post which explicitly said that in LINQ to Objects a join would be better?

Comment: You just modified that answer.:). I just want that we both are on the same track here.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for Inner Join in this context. If I would have used `contains`, it would iterate 6 times despite if the fact that there are just two matches. I just want to emphasize here that I will go for Joins instead of IN predicate.

```
var desiredNames = new[] { "Pankaj" };

var people = new[] 
{ 
    new { FirstName="Pankaj", Surname="Garg" }, 
    new { FirstName="Marc", Surname="Gravell" }, 
    new { FirstName="Jeff", Surname="Atwood" } 
};

var records = (from p in people join filtered in desiredNames on p.FirstName equals filtered select p.FirstName).ToList();
```