# Dynamic Linq query on List <T> using Predicate Builder

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder

I'm using C# 2010  .NET 4.0 and I have a `List<T>` collection called `returns` that I need to build a dynamic LINQ query on.

I'm utilizing the Predicate Builder referenced [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

This works fine if I have 1 filter criteria, but if I have 2 or more, then, when the `query.compile()` is called, I get this error:

> variable 'tmp' of type 'Check21Tools.IncomingReturn' referenced from
>   scope '', but it is not defined

Code:

```
  Expression<Func<Check21Tools.IncomingReturn, bool>> query = null;

  bool hasFilterItems = false;
  if (filterArray != null)
  {
    foreach (string s in filterArray)
    {
      if (s == string.Empty)
      { break; }
      else
      {
        hasFilterItems = true;
        Int64 id = Int64.Parse(s);
        query = query.Or(tmp => tmp.ID == id);
      }

    }
  }
  if (hasFilterItems)
  {
    returns = returns.Where(query.Compile()).CreateFromEnumerable
                  <Check21Tools.IncomingReturns, Check21Tools.IncomingReturn>();
  }
```

Code:

```
 public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
     this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
 {
     if (expr1 == null) return expr2;

     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
         (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), expr1.Parameters);

 }
```

Comment: If you're using `List<T>`, why are you building up an `Expression<>` at all? You can just use straight delegates.

Comment: Can you give me an example of doing that dynamically?  My `filterArray` object holds the id's I need to filter for.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094930/linq-to-objects-predicate-builder for a version of PredicateBuilder which doesn't use expression trees.

Comment: -1: You're not using the PredicateBuilder you linked to. The PredicateBuilder you linked to gives a different `Or` method.

Comment: @ShawnHollon So what do you actually want to do?  What should the result of your query be?

Comment: So, say my `returns` object has 10 items.   and I've generated a list of "ID's" dynamically that I want to filter on.  I want to filter my `returns` from the 10 to say 2 items.   it should work the same as this  
`returns = returns.where(tmp=>tmp.ID == 110 || tmp.ID == 111)`


@hvd, the difference in the OR method is the ORElse is the equivalnt to this  || instead of the OR method using the bitwise of |

Comment: You shouldn't need Predicate Builder for that.  You just need an IN clause.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/423840 and http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/

Comment: @RobertHarvey He's doing LINQ to Objects.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So it's not a LINQ to SQL query...

Comment: @Servy: It doesn't matter.  Linq to SQL returns IEnumerables, and that's all Rob Conery's article is really talking about.  The first link I provided works too.

Comment: I've stumbled across an updated version of the predicate builder to work on List<T> objects
    `public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
      {
         if (expr1 == null) return expr2;
         var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
         return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
      }`

Comment: Don't post code in comments.  As you can see, it's unreadable.  if this is an answer, post it as an answer.  If it is an update to your question, click `edit` and paste the code into your question.

Comment: I do appreciate the input.

Comment: @Robert harvy, the system won't let me post an answer so soon since I'm a New member.  i will be posing this as an answer as soon as the system lets me.  Apparently, I have 7 hours to wait.

Comment: @ShawnHollon: The time delay is imposed on everyone, not just new users.  I put it in an answer for you.

Comment: Also, note the comments I made about the `IN` clause.  If you already have a list of ID's, you don't need Predicate Builder; you can just use `Contains()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The OP has] stumbled across an updated version of the predicate builder that works on `List<T>` objects:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
     if (expr1 == null) return expr2;
     var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
```